# Batch operations with reactive cassandra using spring-data

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, reactive, spring-data-cassandra

I have the following data structure (in pseudo code):

```
class GroupedData
{
  String key;
  List<Tuple<String, String>> records;
}
```

I figured the best way to model this was by doing something like

```
@Table(name="record_by_group)
class DataWithGroup{
  @PrimaryKey(name="group_key")
  String groupKey;
  @PrimaryKey(name="data_key"
  String dataKey;
  String data;
}
```

I would then stream the `GroupedData` into a `DataWithGroup` using batched operations with inside spring. I am doing this inside a webflux application so i am using the reactive cassandra repository what I have noticed is that there is a vanilla `CassandraBatchOperations` but there is no `ReactiveCassandraBatchOperations`. I am wondering if I am missing something or is there a way to insert batch reactively. Alternatively how do I insert a something structured like the `GroupedData` into cassandra I think I should be using composite columns but I couldn't really get my head round them let alone figure out how to map them in using spring-data.

Comment: As of now, there's no reactive `BatchOperations` variant. As a workaround, you could create batch statements yourself and group them into a `Batch`. I filed https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-574 to add reactive batch operations.

Comment: do you have an example of this using the ReactiveCassandra api?